# XSLT transformation to read xml element and value and convert xml data into name value pair

Tags: xml, xslt

> Need below help to adjust the xslt so that if there is repeating multioccurance node example "SalesQuoteParty" then :

1. Only Produce output name value pair if SalesQuoteParty-RoleCode = 39 or 1001 (Need help how to filter party data based on Role Code)
2. Concatenate the value of element RoleCodeText to the name, for example, current output - SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText
   becomes - Owner.SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText

---

```html
Input XML data
<SalesQuoteCollection>
 <SalesQuote>
  <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
  <TaxAmount>0.000000</TaxAmount>
  <PriceDateTime>2020-03-17T14:52:55.439</PriceDateTime>
  <DocumentLanguageCode>EN</DocumentLanguageCode>
  <SalesQuoteParty>
   <SalesQuoteParty>
    <PartyName>Porter LLC</PartyName>
    <PartyID>1001</PartyID>
    <RoleCode>1001</RoleCode>
    <RoleCodeText>Account</RoleCodeText>
    <FirstLineName>Porter LLC</FirstLineName>
   </SalesQuoteParty>
   <SalesQuoteParty>
    <PartyName>Manish Admin</PartyName>
    <PartyID>8000000705</PartyID>
    <RoleCode>39</RoleCode>
    <RoleCodeText>Owner</RoleCodeText>
    <FirstLineName>Mr. Manish Admin</FirstLineName>
   </SalesQuoteParty>
  </SalesQuoteParty>
  <ProcessingTypeCode>AG</ProcessingTypeCode>
 </SalesQuote>
</SalesQuoteCollection>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Current Output using xslt
<group>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.CurrencyCode</Name>
 <Value>GBP</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.TaxAmount</Name>
 <Value>0.000000</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.PriceDateTime</Name>
 <Value>2020-03-17T14:52:55.439</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.DocumentLanguageCode</Name>
 <Value>EN</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.PartyName</Name>
 <Value>Porter LLC</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.PartyID</Name>
 <Value>1001</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCode</Name>
 <Value>1001</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText</Name>
 <Value>Account</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.FirstLineName</Name>
 <Value>Porter LLC</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.PartyName</Name>
 <Value>Manish Admin</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.PartyID</Name>
 <Value>8000000705</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCode</Name>
 <Value>39</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText</Name>
 <Value>Owner</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.FirstLineName</Name>
 <Value>Mr. Manish Admin</Value>
 <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.ProcessingTypeCode</Name>
 <Value>AG</Value>
</group>

Need below help to adjust the xslt so that if there is repeating multioccurance node example "SalesQuoteParty" then :

1. Only Produce output name value pair if SalesQuoteParty-RoleCode = 39 or 1001 (Need help how to filter party data based on Role Code)
2. Concatenate the value of element RoleCodeText to the name, for example, current output - <Name>SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText</Name>
becomes - <Name>Owner.SalesQuoteCollection.SalesQuote.SalesQuoteParty.SalesQuoteParty.RoleCodeText</Name>
```

Comment: Please edit your previous question and delete this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980202/xslt-transformation-to-convert-xml-data-into-name-value-pair

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSLT transformation to convert xml data into name value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980202/xslt-transformation-to-convert-xml-data-into-name-value-pair)